# Urldecode an encodeURI/Component text

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, decode, encode

I have a query which is encoded in JS

```
query = encodeURIComponent(query);
//also tried encodeURI(query); with the same result
var request = $.ajax(
        {
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'add-reciepe.php',
            data: query
        }
    )
```

and on the PHP side I want to encode it with urldecode();

```
$query = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
$query = urldecode($query);
parse_str($query, $out);
```

but the the $query (urldecoded string) output is exactly the same as the input was (cocktail-type=Cocktailtyp+w%C3%A4hlen for example)

The strange thing is, if i write 'Cocktailtyp+w%C3%A4hlen' into the db the text in the db is: Cocktailtyp wÃ¤hlen

mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8'); is set.

Does someone has an idea how I can decode the query string in php or where my problem is?

Comment: are your db-fields utf-8 and did you query("SET NAMES utf8"); after connect to mysql db?

Comment: yes, set names uft8 is called and the db fields are utf8_general_ci , should i use an other one? normally latin1_swedish_c1 works for me (with the german letters) but i dont know why now not